# How to return the a list from a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to return a list from the following recursive function, where should I do it?.
I think I cant manage to do it because I do not fully understand all the function steps so how can I  follow each step of the recursion using the debugger? (pycharm)
Thanks for the helpers!!

```
def parentheses_helper(open, close, word, lst):
    """ get 2 equal integers and return all the combination of balanced parantheses """
    if open == 0 and close == 0:
        lst.append(word) 
        print(lst)
    if open > close:
        return
    if open > 0:
        parentheses_helper(open - 1, close, word + '(', lst)
    if close > 0:
        parentheses_helper(open, close - 1, word + ')', lst)


def parentheses(n):
    parentheses_helper(n, n, '', [])
```

Comment: print(lst) to return lst

Comment: What about `return lst` instead of `return`?

Comment: What is the correct answer you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to return the list from function `parentheses` you can create a list variable inside of it and pass to `parentheses_helper` and then return the variable. This will work, because you are modifying the same list inside of `parentheses_helper` (the list is not getting copied)

```py
def parentheses(n):
    lst = []
    parentheses_helper(n, n, '', lst)
    return lst
```

Comment: Amazing! that worked perfectly. I would love to understand why that happened? The helper function is modifying the lst from the parentheses func?

Comment: @navehroliiir Yes, it does. `lst.append` modifies the list in-place. When you pass a list to a function, it remains the same object and doesn't get copied